# PHP exponential growth by certain factor in given steps

Tags: php

I can't figure out how to do this in PHP.

What I have is:

`$loops=10;`
`$factor=5;`
`$start=20;`
`$end=80;`

So I want to start the loop at 20 and reach the exact number 80 by doing 10 loops and the difference between the output-number per loop should somehow be influenced by the factor 5 (in a exponential way). So all together these numbers would be an exponential curve.

(Actually it's kind of like an easing out Script in Flash where you can define the speed=factor of easing)

Thanks

Comment: You want this our your teacher want this?

Comment: I want this and thanks your comment helped a lot - not!

Comment: Could you explain the role of your factor more clearly. Is it like a gamma - changing the rate of change between the early and late part of the curve?

Comment: Do you know easing Scripts for flash where you define the speed of how fast to ease out - like that only PLUS i want to define in how many loops to get to the end. Does this make it more clear?

Comment: we could also rename the varibles to x_from, x_to, number_of_loops, speed

Answer (score 3):

```
for($i = 20; $i <= 80; $i += 5)
```

Comment: Yes, though you could perform any kind of operation you would like. You could even do `for($i = 20; $i <= 80; )` (leaving out the afterthought) and perform your operation on $i inside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

With both `factor` and `loops` you have overdetermined your problem if you say you want an exponential growth (rather than linear). If you just want expponential growth, then you are looking for a factor (say `alpha`) that is such that `alpha`<sup>`(loops - 1)`</sup> = `end/start`. And then you compute your terms by multiplying the previous term by `alpha`.

```
$alpha = exp(log($end/$start)/($loops-1)));
for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i*=alpha) {
  ...
```

If you want to "somehow use the factor to influence the growth" then "exponential" is the wrong term. You might have to describe a little better what "growth" you really want; I demonstrated in the code above what geometric (or exponential) growth looks like and how to achieve it; but you can increment `$i` in any way you want in order to get from `20` to `80`...

**UPDATE** If you want to change the rate of change, you can create any number of equations (functions) that would cause a "increasing step size". Here are a couple of examples: they go from `0` to `1` as their input parameter changes from `0` to `1` - all you have to do is multiply the output by the range to get it.

```
y = x^factor
y = x ^ (1 / factor)
```

You can use many other... To use such a function you could for example do

```
for($i=1; $i < $loops; $i++) {
  $x = $i / ($loops - 1);
  $value = ($end - $start) * pow($x, $factor) + $start
}
```

This doesn't compute the very first value since `pow` doesn't like it when the base is zero. I am sure you can work around that... (hint - the first value is equal to `$start`).

Comment: I do need both the loops and the factor=the speed of how fast to reach the end

Comment: If you have the beginning, the end, and the number of steps - the only thing left to control is the rate of change of the steps. Are you saying you want that rate to change from step to step? If so - then we need to abandon the "exponential" part of your requirements. Is that OK?

Comment: Yes excactly the rate!

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try it - plot the results, see if you like it. I suspect that a factor as big as 5 will be much too big for you. You can of course do something like `pow($x, (1 + $factor / 10))` to give yourself "fine control" over the rate of change while using "sensible numbers" for the factor...

Comment: Thanks Floris, that code worked quite well already with factor 0.7, I will experiment a bit with it and get back to you.

Comment: Glad to hear it. When you are satisfied with the answer you can mark it as "accepted" with the little check mark... Or ask for further clarification with comments.